# Overlapping stacked bar chart using apexcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, apexcharts, ng-apexcharts

I want to create a bar chart with multiple series overlapping each other.

The stack bar chart places a bar on top of another bar.

I want all bars to start from the bottom like the below example.

[image]

is there any way to achieve this with [apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/)?

what I got:

[image]